# Partition to Image in Norton Ghost 15?

Tags: windows-7, norton-ghost

In Norton Ghost 11.5 we had an option,that is named `Partition to Image`. With this option we could back up a drive completely and easily.

What's the identical option in Norton Ghost 15?

P.S:
I have Win7 x64

Comment: If no one answers, here is the user guide

ftp://ftp.symantec.com/public/english_us_canada/products/ghost/15/manuals/ngh_15_user_guide.pdf

Comment: @Moab, I've already read the user guide, but I couldn't find anything special.

Comment: As far as I know there is no possibility to make a drive or partition image in Norton Ghost 15.